# Is the "Scroll to top" button in Pinterest a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I like the "Scroll to top" button that appears in pinterest.com as soon as you scroll down the screen, and i've noticed that other sites are using it too, so i wondered is it a jQuery plugin or do i have to code my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they have packed their js files into one, so its not possible to say what they are using, eventhough they are using jquery.

It would be much easier to use a jQuery plugin and get it done. Check out this demo

http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/top-of-page-jquery.php

Answer (score 0):

I can't check the link at work, it's blocked under 'Social Networking' but I've used the JQuery plugin ScrollTo to do all sorts of scrolling goodness. It's pretty feature rich.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html